# My Windows 10 never goes to sleep while charging

Tags: windows-10, battery, sleep

More than a year ago I needed to prevent Windows 10 from going to sleep while charging. To accomplish this, since setting the Power Plan to "never" was not enough, I followed some online guide that suggested to modify something in the Registry Editor.

Now I don't need this feature anymore (and of course again, changing the Power Plan is not enough), but I don't even remember what I changed at that time, so at the moment my PC never goes to sleep even if I would like to. I looked for the same guide but I couldn't find it. I specify that while not charging, the PC goes to sleep without problems.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to tell us what registry change you made. Standard Windows Power settings allow a machine to sleep or not sleep (as you choose) without any issue. Be sure you update BIOS and Power Drivers for your machine.

Comment: @John if I remembered that, maybe I wouldn't have asked this question :-) Is there a way to check the most recently changed registry parameters?

Comment: You have to look back and see what you changed in the registry (we do not know). I never had to use registry changes to make the computer sleep properly.

Comment: I spent some time thinking about this. You may be best to back up your stuff,  reinstall Windows and then use Windows tools (not the registry) to manage power. I do and power management works fine.

Comment: @john thanks for the suggestion, although It would be too burdensome for me at the moment to reinstall windows

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify.

The explanation is **Modern Standby** which was introduced in Windows 10 for many new laptops. Modern Standby (**S0 Low Power Idle**), if available, consumes more power and enables faster startup than the traditional **S3** Standby, which you're probably missing. Your laptop is probably in **Modern Standby** which is not the traditional Sleep (**S3**).

According to [Modern Standby](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/disable-modern-standby-in-windows-10-and-windows-11.3929/#2) you can disable Modern Standby (**S0 Low Power Idle**) and thereby re-enable **S3** by running the following command in an elevated command prompt

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power /v PlatformAoAcOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0​
```

However, first you should run the following command in an elevated command prompt

```
powercfg /a
```

That will tell you if **S0 Low Power Idle** or **S3** is available on your system. If **S0 Low Power Idle** is available, you can try to disable it. Remember to restart your laptop after adding the registry entry.

Finally, I should mention that the Windows 11 update of week 38, 2022, seems to have improved **S0 Low Power Idle** significantly, thereby making my laptop sleep the way I would expect it to do.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Instead of posting a new answer, please edit your existing one to incorporate the additional information from this one.

Comment: Then its time to delete one account !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try advanced power settings:

[image]

There are some settings that are not visible directly in control panel:
[image]

Comment: Unluckily, I already managed to get here, I also restored plan defaults, but this was useless.